# C++ Memory Address of const class instances

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, embedded

I am using GCC 6.3.1 for ARM on CORTEX-M4 with `-O2`.

If I have a simple class instance like this:

```
class Test
{
  public:
    void Print(void) const
    {
      printf("Test");
    }
};
const static Test test;
```

and somewhere I refer the address of that object like:

```
printf("Address: %X", &test);
```

then I can see in the map file that the compiler reserves one byte for that address in the `.bss` segment:

```
.bss._ZL4test 0x20005308 0x1
```

Reserving one byte is logical since each object that is addressed must have an address. On the other side I would assume that for something simple like this the compiler would reserve space in the `.text` segment which does not cost any RAM space.

Now I could force the object into the `.text` segment by changing the definition to:

```
const static Test test __attribute__ ((section (".text")));
```

But then it is ALWAYS forced into that segment. This means the object will not work anymore when someone inserts a non const member variable.

Is there any way to tell g++ to put the address of such objects (without any member variables) into the FLASH instead of RAM (without using `__attribute__`)?

Comment: First of all think about the *purpose* of this class. What requirement is it supposed to solve? What part of the design does it implement? Should it be possible to add non-const functions to the class? Perhaps you want a `namespace` instead? Or a class or struct of only `static` member functions?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Not sure what are you are trying to tell me here or how your comment relates to this specific problem... The purpose of this class is to demonstrate the compilers behavior.

Comment: the 1 byte thing is a bit strange to me.   An address is 4 bytes on a cortex M4.  Its also very strange that its in BSS.  There's nothing in your class or that I can think of in the infrastructure that would would require a zero initialized value.

Comment: @RussSchultz: Addresses are 4 byte wide, but one byte gets **reserved**.

Comment: What happens, if you add a `constexpr` constructor? Read-only objects usually put into `.rodata` section.

Comment: @geza: Wow. Thanks. That was the solution. Can you change your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Why do you need an instance of the class? To call the member functions in it, right? But will the class ever contain any data, any member variables? No? Then why do you need an instance? Why not make the member functions `static`, and then you don't need to worry about where the instance might be since there isn't any instance to begin with. That's one of the things I meant by you needing to think about the purpose of the class. *How will it be used?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `constexpr` constructor, and the created object is `const`, then GCC will put the object into the `.rodata` section automatically.